# How to put each set of localized NIBs into its own Bundle, in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to put each set of localized NIBs into its own Bundle, in iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a localized copy of your nib via the File Inspector. Just add localizations by adding languages via the plus-sign

[image: File Inspector: Localizations]